# Grilling beef steak on a contact grill

Tags: grilling, steak

Should I use both sides of a contact grill when doing a beef steak or is it better to use just one side and flip the meat after some time?

The grill I own is **Catler gr4011**

Comment: I've done it from both sides with no problems.  You just want to make sure to pre-heat the grill and pat the steak dry w/ paper towels before cooking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both sides. As Joe said make sure it is nice and hot for when you put the meat on, for 1-2 minutes, so it cooks the outer layer quickly and then reduce to med heat and cook for 4 minutes so you can keep a nice soft texture inside. Times apply for a 24 oz steak. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: If you're going for medium rare, it might be better to leave it on high and just pull it after the surface is grill marks.  If you're going for well done .... then I just can't help you.

Comment: Agreed with Joe, except the most important step: let it rest, after grilling! Too many people forget this step.